# If textbox empty, return true or show confirmation

Tags: javascript, html

If textbox empty, return `true`
else, show confirmation

Working Test: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/KfD3oznkl3eBXgPx

#### What I am trying to do:

When user enter try to click "submit" and the password textfield is blank , then it should return `true` directly, but if password textfield have data, it should show confirm prompt out.

#### What I have done:

When password textfield is empty, it directly returns `true`, but when have value, it show confirmation, but even I click on "no" in the confirmation box, it returns `true`

Code:

```html
<script>
function validateForm(e) {
  var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (password==""){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    confirm("Are You Sure you wanted to change password?");
  }
}
</script>
<h1> Edit Profile </h1>
<form onSubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname"><br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password"><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="email" id="email"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="check" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: @azad Please (if possible) don't link w3schools.com for reference. It is an incomplete, and inexact information source. Please refer to, for example, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) instead

Comment: @FZs yes I agreed, I thought a simple explanation about JS `confirm()` in w3schools is enough for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

confirm returns a boolean value that you are not using in your program.
Try adding return before confirm to actually make use of the value given by the confirm function

```
if (password==""){
    return true;
}
else{
  return confirm("Are You Sure you wanted to change password?");
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

[**`Window.confirm()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

> Returns a boolean value indicating whether OK (true) or Cancel (false) was selected. If a browser is ignoring in-page dialogs, then result is always false.

You should check the value returned by `confirm`

```js
function validateForm(e) {
  var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (password==""){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    var confirmRes = confirm("Are You Sure you wanted to change password?");
    return confirmRes;
    //OR Simply
    //return confirm("Are You Sure you wanted to change password?");
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> Edit Profile </h1>
<form onSubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname"><br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password"><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="email" id="email"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="check" value="OK">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`confirm` API will return `true` or `false` based on user selection. So you can just return the value from `confirm` as below

```
function validateForm(e) {
   var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
   return password === "" || confirm("Are You Sure you wanted to change password?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code See if it works:

```js
function validateForm(e) {
          var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
          if (password==""){
              document.getElementById("myform").submit();
          }
          else{
            if(confirm("Are You Sure you wanted to change password?")){
              document.getElementById("myform").submit();
            }
          }
      }
```

```html
<h1> Edit Profile </h1>
    <form id="myform">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" value="Tommy" id="uname"><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password"><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email" value="test@gmail.com" id="email"><br>
      <input type="button" id="check" value="OK" onclick="validateForm()">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return false instead of true when password is empty. That's you don't have to submit the form when the password is not entered. Also require a return statement in for confirm. Make your changes as follows.

```
function validateForm(e) {
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (password==""){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return confirm("Are You Sure you wanted to change password?");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i checked the confirm value in the else section.

```js
      function validateForm(e) {
      
          var password=document.getElementById("password").value;
          if (password==""){
              return true;
          }
          else{
            var r = confirm("Are You Sure you wanted to change password?");
            if (r == true){
              return true;
            }
            else {
              return false;
            }
          }
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Edit Profile </h1>
    <form onSubmit="return validateForm()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" value="Tommy" id="uname"><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password"><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email" value="test@gmail.com" id="email"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="check" value="OK">
    </form>
```